# How do I fetch more than 100000 rows with Ebean and mysql

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, ebean

In my Company table I have 2 million rows that I want to fetch and perform some operations on. I have written a service class and a method for extracting ids. But it only fetches
100000 rows by default. I have looked through the Ebean docs but I can't find out why.

**Simplified Serviceclass:**

```
public static List<Long> getAllIds(){   

    String sql = "select distinct c.id from Company c where c.state='PUBLISHED'";
    List<SqlRow> sqlRows =
            Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).findList();

    Logger.info("Rows: "+sqlRows.size());               

    return new ArrayList<Long>(0);
}
```

**Gives me:**

```
Rows: 100000
```

Why? How do I solve this? I do not want a limit when fetching.

Comment: That's not really an answer, but often, operations on that many rows are best performed within the database... What are those operations?

Comment: You are correct. But in this case I need get the ids, get some more information that is not available in the db. Then split it up and create som callable tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can set the max results returned by calling the [setMaxRows](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html#setMaxRows%28int%29) method. 
The number that you use might need to be gotten from another query that gets the number of rows in that table.

Untested...

```
public static List<Long> getAllIds(){   

    String sql = "select distinct c.id from Company c where c.state='PUBLISHED'";
    SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);    
    sqlQuery.setMaxRows(3000000);
    List<SqlRow> sqlRows = sqlQuery.findList();

    Logger.info("Rows: "+sqlRows.size());               

    return new ArrayList<Long>(0);
}
```

Comment: Hmm found this in the source code private static final int GLOBAL_ROW_LIMIT = 1000000; so I guess your way is the correct way. Thank you!

Comment: The GLOBAL_ROW_LIMIT of 1,000,000 is there so stop accidental rogue queries. So yes, setting an explicit max rows is the correct solution for this issue (I'm the author of Ebean ORM).